# Controller As inheritance with $controller

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, controller

I have a [pretty big question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032088/controller-inheritance-with-injection) about this issue but I thought it might be easy to split it in smaller ones.

So, I'm trying to use $controller to inherit from a ParentController, but things are not working as expected.

I have a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/danaya/zhyjzbmp/).
And this is the code.

```
angular
    .module("app",[])
    .controller('ParentController', ParentController)
    .controller('ChildController', ChildController)

    ParentController.$inject = ['$scope']
    ChildController.$inject = ['$controller', '$scope'];

function ParentController($scope) {
    var vm = this;    

    vm.foo = 'parent foo';
}

function ChildController($controller, $scope) {

    $controller('ParentController as vm', {$scope: $scope});

        var vm = $scope.vm; // view model       
}
```

And a simple html

```
<div>
  {{vm.foo}}
</div>
```

When I configure the app to use the ParentController, with this

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ParentController as vm">
```

it works fine.

But as it is now, with the ChildController, is not working, it's like vm does not include the property foo created in ParentController.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to go with this approach then you need to extend child controller with base parent controller. You can use angular.extend for this:

```
function ChildController($controller, $scope) {
    angular.extend(this, $controller('ParentController', {$scope: $scope}));
    this.bar = 'child bar';
}
```

Just make sure you first extend child controller instance object (`this`) with parent controller instance, and only after that you define new child properties.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/mdyCOUdZSLUV06AMnoZG?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! That works fine with vars but I tried to create a new function and it's not working fine.
[http://plnkr.co/edit/Cq6CB8srju5lbJhFDbFO?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cq6CB8srju5lbJhFDbFO?p=preview)

Comment: @david It works with methods too. The problem is that you used `var` for function expression and they don't hoist. You should use function declaration instead if you want to put the function after `vm.someValue = someValue;` assignment. http://plnkr.co/edit/EhjWgbPSNQvfn68WvYul?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div>
  {{vm.foo}}
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
  angular
    .module("app",[])
    .controller('ParentController', ParentController)
    .controller('ChildController', ChildController)

    ParentController.$inject = ['$scope']
    ChildController.$inject = ['$controller', '$scope'];

function ParentController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.obj={};
    vm.obj.foo = 'parent foo';
    console.log('parent',vm.obj);
}

function ChildController($controller, $scope) {

  $controller('ParentController as vm', {$scope: $scope});

    var vm = vm; // view model      
    console.log("child",$scope.vm.obj);
}
```